# java.lang.String to type developerjr.evertmoreno.ime.Friends

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase, string, fragment

Cuando trato de pasar al Tap de Friends se me cierra la App y me dice que el error es por un String en la clase Friend pero no veo que pueda ser el error..

```
08-17 17:17:03.521 18367-18367/developerjr.evertmoreno.ime E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: developerjr.evertmoreno.ime, PID: 18367
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type developerjr.evertmoreno.ime.Friends

at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:163)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:152)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:195)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6389)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5335)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5598)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1648)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:343)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:628)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

08-17 17:17:05.581 18367-18367/developerjr.evertmoreno.ime I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18367 SIG: 9
```

Mi Clase Friends

```
package developerjr.evertmoreno.ime;

/**
 * Created by Ever on 16/08/2017.
 */

public class Friends {
    public String date;

    //public Friends(){}

    public Friends(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Mi Fragment Friends

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mFriendsList;
    private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

    private View mMainView;


    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

        mFriendsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(Friends.class,
            R.layout.users_single_layout,
            FriendsViewHolder.class,
            mFriendsDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, Friends friends, int i) {

                friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());
                final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();
                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {
                            String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                            friendsViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);
                        }

                        friendsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                        friendsViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());
                        friendsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open Profile", "Send message"};

                            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                            builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                    //Click Event for each item.
                                    if(i == 0){

                                        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            startActivity(profileIntent);
                                        }
                                        if(i == 1){
                                           Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                           chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                           chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                builder.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }


    public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDate(String date){
            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(date);
        }

    public void setName(String name){
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }

        public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){
            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.with (ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default1).into(userImageView);
        }
        public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {
            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.drawable.online_icon);
            if(online_status.equals("true")){
                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mi PagerAdapter:

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                RequestsFragment requestsFragment = new RequestsFragment();
                return requestsFragment;
            case 1:
                ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                return  chatsFragment;
            case 2:
                FriendsFragment friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment();
                return friendsFragment;

            default:
                return  null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "REQUESTS";
            case 1:
                return "CHATS";
            case 2:
                return "FRIENDS";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es con un String de la clase Friend. El error indica que los objetos en el nodo de la BD a la que estas apuntando tu Firebase adapter están representando Strings y no información que se pueda utilizar para componer un "Friend".

Los datos en cada hijo de `/Friends/<user_id>` deberian corresponderse a los campos publicos de Friend.